# Android app interface with standard phone call

Tags: android, microphone, phone-call

I want to know if its possible to create an app that activates in the background when the user gets a phone call ? and if it is possible I'd like to know where I can find more information about how the app can interact with the phone call.

For example, is it possible to turn off / on the mic during a call or intercept it, add sounds in the background etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "Broadcast Receiver" available in the API Android.

Here tutorials about those (specific to your very question):
http://androidexample.com/Incomming_Phone_Call_Broadcast_Receiver__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=61&aaid=86

And another :
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#tutorial_receiver